# Logitech scripting combining keystroke and mouse click

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to make a script that repeatedly clicks left mouse button when I hold left control key with left mouse button at the same time

This is what I have so far:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)
  OutputLogMessage("clicked event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg);
 if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Ctrl_Down == 1 then
      repeat
      PressMouseButton(1) //repeat while the left mouse button down
      until not PressMouseButton(1)
     else ReleaseMouseButton(3) //stop the repating on left mouse button up
  end

end
```

Please note this is my first time looking over this type of coding as any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to define `EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents()` to enables event reporting for mouse button 1

To avoid any endless loop you have to put `sleep()`;

> Press left control key then left mouse button it will repeat the click
>   until you release the left mouse button then release left control key
>   the script should be stopped

Your final code should be like:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsModifierPressed("lctrl") then
        repeat  
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                    PressMouseButton(1)
                    Sleep(15)
                    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end             
        until not IsModifierPressed("lctrl")
    end         
end
```

Comment: Awesome! this exactly what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

What you are specifically looking for may not be possible with the api.

When you call `PressMouseButton(1)` this changes the state of the left mouse button. when you call `ReleaseMouseButton(1)` the same is true even if you are still pressing the button, the script will see it as released. This means you can't use `IsMouseButtonPressed(1)` to detect if the button is still pressed.

To create a "click" you would need to use `PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)` and with this you can no longer detect when **YOU** stop pressing the mouse button. As an alternative you can look at the ctrl key and see if it is still pressed, using `IsModifierPressed("ctrl")`.

The following should repeat after a left click with ctrl down is detected and only end once ctrl has been released:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)
    OutputLogMessage("clicked event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg);
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Ctrl_Down == 1 then
        repeat
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1) --repeat while the ctrl is still pressed
        until not IsModifierPressed("ctrl")
    end
end
```

This information is based on the *Logitech G-series Lua API V3.02*.

Comment: @Liam Is it entering the if statement? i couldn't find information to confirm this condition `Ctrl_Down == 1` it may need to be replaced with `IsModifierPressed("ctrl")`

Comment: It's still repeating the click the script not stopping

Comment: Is its repeating within the `repeat` loop endlessly? or is `PressAndReleaseMouseButton` causing recursive calls to `OnEvent`? if your seeing multiple `OutputLogMessage` than it is `OnEvent` if that is the case can remove the `repeat` loop all together.

Comment: it's repeating within the repeat loop endlessly it causing lag to the pc, I need to restart the PC to fix it